# Representation of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, markov-process

If $\Omega$ is a countable set, every linear operator mapping $\mathbb R^\Omega$ to itself can be represented as a matrix $M\colon \Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

In the case $\Omega$ is uncountable, and if we settle on a particular $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $\Omega$, I am wondering if some nice linear operators on $\Omega$ can be represented as a "matrix" $M\colon\Omega\times\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$.

In particular, consider a measurable space $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, where $\Sigma\subseteq \{0,1\}^\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra for $\Omega$. A (sub-)Markov kernel is a map $L\colon \Omega\times\Sigma\to[0,1]$ such that for each $x\in \Omega$, we have

$$
\int L(x,\mathrm{d}y) \le 1.
$$

Now consider a measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$. The function space $\mathcal H= \mathcal L_2(\Omega,\mu)$ endowed with the natural inner product 
\begin{align*}
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_\Omega fg\,\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align*}
is a Hilbert space, therefore we may speak of linear operators $A$ mapping a subspace $D_A$ of $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$. I am wondering if for every linear operator $A\colon D_A\to\mathcal H$ of which $\mathcal L_1\to \mathcal L_1$ norm is bounded, there are reals $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$ and Markov kernels $L_1,L_2$ such that $A=c_1L_1 + c_2L_2$. This latter equality is understood as the following: for all $f\in D_A$, we have $fA = c_1 fL_1 + c_2fL_2$

Here we need to allow two Markov kernels because $A$ may not be positivity preserving.
Thanks

Comment: "Bounded linear operator" - on what function space, and with respect to what norm?

Comment: @NateEldredge I have added more information. Please let me know if this is still not enough to make this question well-defined. Thank you.

Comment: The $L_1$ metric only makes sense once you specify a measure.  And typically it isn't well defined (or finite) on all of $\mathbb{R}^{\Omega}$.  It might be that you need to do some more background study about these objects before formulating a question?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you, it appears that I need a bit more background for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sub-Markov kernel, or any linear combination thereof, has the property that it maps bounded functions to bounded functions.  So any bounded operator without this property will be a counterexample.

For a specific example, take $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mu$ Lebesgue measure, and let $h : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded function in $\mathcal{L}^1 \cap \mathcal{L}^2$.  For instance, $h(x) = x^{-1/3}$ would do.  Then choose a functional which is continuous in both $\mathcal{L}^1$ and $\mathcal{L}^2$ norms, such as for instance the integral, and multiply by $h$.  So we could consider
$$Af(x) = \int_0^1 f(t)\,dt \cdot h(x).$$
This is a bounded operator with respect to either the $\mathcal{L}^1$ or $\mathcal{L}^2$ norms.  If it were of the form $A = c_1 L_1 + c_2 L_2$ then we would have, for instance, $|A1(x)| \le |c_1| + |c_2|$ for (almost?) every $x$.  But $A1=h$ which does not have this property.

Comment: Thank you very much. Was the $\mathcal L^\infty\to\mathcal L^\infty$ being unbounded the main distinguishing factor, or representing linear operators via maps such as $\Omega\times\Sigma\to\mathbb R$ completely hopeless?

Comment: I don't know in general.

Comment: @KuwabaraDosetsu: Since you're allowing unbounded operators, the derivative operator might be a good one to consider.  It seems unlikely that you can write it as the difference of two positivity preserving operators (though I don't immediately see how to prove that).